# Continue Execution even after program catches exception

Tags: java, exception

here is a sample:

```
class A{

    method1(){
     int result = //do something
     if(result > 1){
      method2();
     } else{
       // do something more
     }
    }

    method2(){
     try{
       // do something
     } catch(Exception e){
       //throw a message
      }

     }
    }
```

when situation is something like this.

When the catch block inside Method2 is called, I want the program to continue execution and move back to the else block inside Method 1. How can I achieve this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
class A{

method1(){
 int result = //do something
 if(result > 1){
   method2();
 }else{
   method3(); 
 }
}

method2(){
   try{
   // do something
   } catch(Exception e){ // If left at all exceptions, any error will call Method3()
     //throw a message
     //Move to call method3()
     method3();
   }
 }

 method3(){
  //What you origianlly wanted to do inside the else block

 }
}

}
```

In this situation, the program will call Method3 if it moves into the catch block inside method 2. While inside Method1, the else block also calls method3. This will imitate the program 'moving back' to the else block from the catch block

Comment: thanks, but there is no way I could figure out the most specific exception which is gonna be thrown within try. and without the specific exception the execution will go higher and would never invoke method3

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by "the execution will go higher and would never invoke method3". In the situation above, if an exception is ever called and it moves into the Catch Block, Method 3 will automatically be called. You don't HAVE to have a specific exception, sorry that was my mistake, but if you have situations where you don't want to call Method3() when there is an exception you will need to have another Catch Block

Comment: No I don't, simpily because if somehow an unexpected error occurred during the try block in method 2, the program would still run method3 regardless... This can be used in very specific examples where method3 is a 'crash prevention' method, in that case then sure this idea can work. However if you can avoid it please do.    On a side note: if my answer solved your question please accept it!

Answer (score 4):

Simply encapsulate the call of `method2` in a `try-catch` block. Catching the exception will not allow the unhandled exception to be thrown. Do something like this:

```
if(result > 1){
    try {
         method2();
     } catch(Exception e) { //better add specific exception thrwon from method2
         // handling the exception gracefully
     }
   } else{
       // do something more
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. but how would it end up executing the code in else block . your logic is perfect I am just having hard time understanding How would it end up being in else block

Comment: @Ashish The code i have given will just handle the exception gracefully. It will not execute the code in the else block. If and else blocks are mutually exlusive i.e only one can execute at a time. If you have some code that you want to execute in case of both exception in if block and normal else block execution, then move the code of else block in a method. And call that method from the both the catch block in if block and normal else block.

Answer (score 0):

You need a double `if` instead.

```
method1()
{
    if(result > 1)
    {
        if(method2()) { execute code }
        else { what you wanted to do in the other code }
    }
}
```

and ofc let method 2 return something (in this case I let it return bool for easy check)