# java exception to continue code loop

Tags: java, exception

How can I resume code shown below, so that if the first try gets an exception the code execusion will still carry on to the 2nd try. at the moment, if I get an exception on the first try, the code does not continue to the next try below it.

```
Calendar facebook_check_post_date = Calendar.getInstance();
facebook_check_post_date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -4);
long facebook_check_post_Unix_Time = facebook_check_post_date.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;    
String query = "SELECT message,timeline_visibility, created_time   FROM stream WHERE source_id = 187050104663230 AND message AND strlen(attachment.fb_object_type) < 1 AND type != 56 AND type = 46  AND strpos(message, \"prayer time(s)\") < 0 AND strpos(message, \"White days\") < 0 AND strpos(message, \"Hadith of the Day:\") < 0 AND created_time > " + facebook_check_post_Unix_Time + "LIMIT 1";

try 
{
List<JsonObject> queryResults = facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(query, JsonObject.class);
facebook_post = queryResults.get(0).getString("message");
facebook_post_visibility = queryResults.get(0).getString("timeline_visibility");
facebook_Label_visible = true;                                      facebook_created_time_calendar.setTimeInMillis(queryResults.get(0).getLong("created_time")* 1000);
out.print("Comment posted on:"); 
out.println(facebook_created_time_calendar.getTime());
}
catch (FacebookException e){Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication4.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);}  

query = "SELECT fan_count FROM page WHERE page_id = 187050104663230";
try 
{
List<JsonObject> queryResults = facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(query, JsonObject.class);
facebook_Fan_Count = queryResults.get(0).getString("fan_count");
out.println(facebook_Fan_Count);
}
catch (FacebookException e){Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication4.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);}
```

Comment: If it doesn't get to the next statement, it means you were catching the wrong exception.

Comment: what do you mean it does not continue? It is supposed to continue (besides the log). Is there an error in the second try?

Comment: I realise i was not catching the correct exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Exception instead of FacebookException:

```
Calendar facebook_check_post_date = Calendar.getInstance();
facebook_check_post_date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -4);
long facebook_check_post_Unix_Time = facebook_check_post_date.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;    
String query = "SELECT message,timeline_visibility, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id =     187050104663230 AND message AND strlen(attachment.fb_object_type) < 1 AND type != 56 AND type = 46      AND strpos(message, \"prayer time(s)\") < 0 AND strpos(message, \"White days\") < 0 AND     strpos(message, \"Hadith of the Day:\") < 0 AND created_time > " + facebook_check_post_Unix_Time + "LIMIT 1";

try 
{
    List<JsonObject> queryResults = facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(query, JsonObject.class);
    facebook_post = queryResults.get(0).getString("message");
    facebook_post_visibility = queryResults.get(0).getString("timeline_visibility");
    facebook_Label_visible = true;
    facebook_created_time_calendar.setTimeInMillis(queryResults.get(0).getLong("created_time")* 1000);
    out.print("Comment posted on:"); 
    out.println(facebook_created_time_calendar.getTime());
}
catch (Exception e)    {
    Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication4.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
}  

query = "SELECT fan_count FROM page WHERE page_id = 187050104663230";
try 
{
    List<JsonObject> queryResults = facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(query, JsonObject.class);
    facebook_Fan_Count = queryResults.get(0).getString("fan_count");
    out.println(facebook_Fan_Count);
}
catch (Exception e){
    Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication4.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I assume it is safer to use Exception e instead of specific exception to ensure everything is caught

Comment: It's even smarter to show ui notification with exception details inside catch

Comment: Well, I see that you use JavaFX. Here you can find an example of PopupWindow: https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1926196 Just put the proper code inside catch block

Comment: Use e.getMessage() for getting exception details

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the code within the second try block in a method. 
invoke this method from the catch block of the first try.

have a look at this
    [Continue Execution even after program catches exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712745/continue-execution-even-after-program-catches-exception)